# PHP: how generate random hex color within a certain range hue or brightness?

Tags: php, hex

I found helpful php method to generate random hex color values but they can output colors from black to 255 white right?

but i was wondering if i can set a 'range' so the colors are only within two parameters or something:

eg. random "yellows" or all pastel colors, or only bright colors excluding dark or black... etc

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code excerpt which uses the `min` and `max` parameters to `rand()` to limit the range of the returned values (min ≥ 0, min ≤ max, max ≤ 255):

```
$r = rand($min_r, $max_r);
$g = rand($min_g, $max_g);
$b = rand($min_b, $max_b);
```

Which we can then combine into a color reference.

```
$c = ($r << 16) + ($g << 8) + $b; 
$hex = dechex($c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Gavriel's answer seems to have a couple of shortcomings.

In particular the combining of the r, g & b into a color reference may not yield a legal 6-hexdigit color reference.  Also it needs a leading '#'.  I would suggest replacing the last line with something like:

```
$colref = "#" . substr("000000".dechex($n), -6);
```

Also, if you are starting with concepts like "yellows" or "pastels" or "dark colors", it is probably more natural to start with the HSV (Hue Saturation Value) color system and then convert that to RGB.  If so, here is a [function for the conversion from HSV to RGB](https://gist.github.com/Jadzia626/2323023)

Comment: good point about the HSV... i havent thought about